# Message broadcasted multiple times in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am relatively new to node.js and socket.io. While building a sample chat room application I am encountering a case where when I refresh the browser n times, and then send a message, the message gets broadcasted n-times to all the clients. How do I make it not broadcast multiple times and just once? Here goes the server side and client side code.

```
  qaserver.js

  var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { log : false });

server.listen(4040);

var redis = require('redis');
var r43 = redis.createClient('6379', '127.0.0.1');
r43.select("43");

// Set the view directory to /views
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

// Let's use the Jade templating language
app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.get("/", function(request, response) {
  response.end("Welcome to the homepage!");
});

app.get("/qaclient", function(request, response) {
response.render("qaclient", { message: "Welcome to QA Forum" });
io.sockets.once('connection', function (socket) {


    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(){

            // store the username in the socket session for this client
            socket.join('test_room');
            socket.room='test_room';
            console.log("------------- List of connected clients on adduser -------------------");
            var clients = io.sockets.clients('test_room'); //
            console.log(clients);
            //socket.username = username;
            socket.emit("welcome_fn",socket.room);
            // echo to client they've connected

    });

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
    //io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('broadcast_message', data.name,data.message);
    console.log("------------- List of connected clients on message broadcast -------------------");
    var clients = io.sockets.clients('test_room'); //
    console.log(clients);
    socket.broadcast.to('test_room').emit('broadcast_message', data.name,data.message);
    //io.sockets.emit('broadcast_message', data.name,data.message);
    console.log(data.name);
    console.log(data.message);

});

// when the user disconnects.. perform this
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                // remove the username from global usernames list
                console.log('Socket disconnected : ');
                console.log(socket.room);
                socket.leave('test_room');

                //console.log(socket.leave(socket.room));
        });

});


});
```

--

```
qaclient.js

window.onload = function() {
     var messages = [];
    var field = document.getElementById("message");
    sendButton = document.getElementById("sendbutton");
    //var content = document.getElementById("content");
    var name = document.getElementById("name");

 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4040');

  // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
    socket.on('connect', function(){
            // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
            socket.emit('adduser');
    });  

    socket.on('welcome_fn',function(room)
    {
        chatcontent.innerHTML = "<b>Welcome to Chat central.. Type your message to start chatting in room "+ room +"</b>";
    });

  socket.on('broadcast_message', function (name,message) {
  var data=new Object();

  data.message=message;
  data.username=name;
    if(message) {
            messages.push(data);
            var html = '';
            console.log(messages.length);
            for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
                html += '<b>' + messages[i].username + ': </b>';
                html += messages[i].message + '<br />';
            }
            chatcontent.innerHTML = html;
        }
    //socket.emit('message', { name: name; message:field });
  });

  sendButton.onclick = function() {
      if($.trim(field.value)=="")
      {
        alert("Enter the message Foo!");
      }
      else
      {
          name_tosend_tmp=name.value;
          name_tosend= name_tosend_tmp.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
          message_tosend_tmp=field.value;
          message_tosend= message_tosend_tmp.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");

          socket.emit('message', { name: name_tosend , message:message_tosend });
          var data=new Object();
          data.message=message_tosend;
          data.username=name_tosend;
          messages.push(data);
          var html = '';
          for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
            html += '<b>' + messages[i].username + ': </b>';
            html += messages[i].message + '<br />';
          }
          chatcontent.innerHTML = html;
          document.getElementById("name").value="";
          document.getElementById("message").value="";
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the click event fires twice or the socket.on 'message'

Comment: I did. The click event fires only once..  socket.on('message') on the server gets fired multiple times..

Comment: Im having the same problem. Did you end up figuring out what was wrong?

Comment: I am having a similar issue too. would appreciate if you share your findings on it ?

Comment: hello  @sniper were you able to find a soln to problem